# Why are there two different throttle designs for the 757 and 767?

Tags: boeing, throttle, boeing-757, boeing-767

There is this one, which seems to be the older version. Notice there is a big gap between each lever, except at the top.

[image]

And this one. Notice there is almost no gap between each lever, making it appear "bulkier."

[image]

Comment: What do you see as being different?  They both look like dark metal on the outside and light gray concave on the inside.

Comment: Any difference between the photos is probably due to lighting and color cast.

Comment: @Jim I'm pretty sure OP refers to the levers themselves, not the "handles". The ones on the bottom are bulkier.

Comment: @DeepSpace Correct. The levers are the same, but the handles on the second ones are much “bulkier,” as you described.

Comment: There is even a third design used on the 767-400ER, based on the 777 thrust levers. See [this Boeing magazine](https://www.boeing.com/commercial/aeromagazine/aero_09/flight.pdf).

Comment: I think it depends on what is behind the throttle levers, but that's just a garden variety wild-a** guess.

Comment: It's possible that the difference in the throttle housing is because the B767 engines (at least with some engines) is controlled by cables from the throttle (larger housing is necessary) and the B757 engines are controlled by wires from the throttle (electronic control).

Comment: @757toga So, is the difference in engine control based on the manufacturer? For instance, let's say RR uses cables, but GE uses wires.